# Ubuntu Weird Internet Issue [USB/WiFi Tether]

Tags: networking, internet, dns

i have an weird problem with internet connection (LTE Network Tethered over USB/WiFi) on my Ubuntu 16.4 Desktop. Webpages load slowly and pings are high when i do `ping 4.2.2.4` or `ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
thebitbrine@TheBitBrine-Pc:~$ ping 4.2.2.4
PING 4.2.2.4 (4.2.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=997 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=1004 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=1050 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=1047 ms
```

and doing `sudo apt-get update` takes up to 30 mins with ~1,300B/s transfer rate
but when i'm doing a speed test on [Speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) it shows me normal rates:

> Ping: 30ms : Download: ~17.3Mb/s : Upload: ~5.4Mb/s :
>   [[Original Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcwbg.png)]

tried changing DNS to nearest server but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Open software properties**

> `sudo software-properties-gtk`

**Change *download from* to another**

[image]

**Update repository**

> sudo apt-get update